# Grab 1 Url from an Excel cell that has 3 in it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel cell that contains 3 url's and some surrounding text in one long string:

```
Product Image URL: http://www.Website.com/product_images/y/099/7703_269_ImageDescription1.jpg|Product Image URL: http://www.Website.com/product_images/c/999/7703_269_ImageDescription2.jpg|Product Image URL: http://www.Website.com/product_images/r/560/7703_269_ImageDescription3.jpg
```

I need to grab the first URL with no spaces so I can send it to another cell on its own (I need to do this for every row).

I have researched the solutions but I can't seem to find one that matches my situation, and I am new to the formulas on Excel.  Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that you have your text in A1:

```
Product Image URL: http://www.Website.com/product_images/y/099/7703_269_ImageDescription1.jpg|Product Image URL: http://www.Website.com/product_images/c/999/7703_269_ImageDescription2.jpg|Product Image URL: http://www.Website.com/product_images/r/560/7703_269_ImageDescription3.jpg
```

You can write your formula like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,FIND("|",A1)-FIND(":",A1)-2)
```

And it will give you this result:

```
http://www.Website.com/product_images/y/099/7703_269_ImageDescription1.jpg
```

The explanation of the formula is:

> MID(text, start, length)

Will return a subtext from a text, in this case from A1 we will find the first ":", and from there find the next "|", and return the text within.

> FIND(text_searched, text_complete)

Will return the position of the text we are searching withing the complete text.

So, into MID we put the whole text, the start of the subtext is the position of the ":" +2, to ignore the ":" and the next space.
The length of the subtext is defined by the position of the "|" minus the position of the ":".

**Edit:**
In case your A1 cell only has one value, the 2nd parameter of MID needs to be just bigger to the length of the text we want to obtain, and it can stay like:

> =MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,LEN(A1))

Where we know LEN(A1) is longer than a subset of A1.

**Second Edit:**

If we merge both, we just need to check for error when looking for the "|" char. If it is found, return the length until that, if it is not found, return the LEN(A1).

> =MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("|",A1)),LEN(A1),FIND("|",A1)-FIND(":",A1)-2))

Comment: does the trick, nice one

Comment: If you mark the post as answer, i'll be thankful

Comment: Could this be formatted to also work if the field only has one url without the | character at the end?  ( upped your answer, says it won't show but it does credit you)

Comment: @Tron Just updated the answer for the case of only one url

Comment: Thanks Fernando, I actually meant if it could be revised to account for either - meaning can it be written to extract that first url but if there is only one it can grab it?  Right now we are using the "|" character so it knows when to stop but what if it just stops at the end?

Comment: @Tron Just adding some error check if the "|" char is not found will do the trick. If "|" then the first formula, if not, then the second formula.

Answer (score 0):

After some research trial and error:

=MID(G2, FIND("Product Image URL:", G2) +19, (FIND("|Product Image URL:", G2)-(FIND("Product Image URL:", G2) +19)))

Where G2 is the field with the URL's.